# how to create a password protected ovpn client configuration?

Tags: 18.04, password, vpn, openvpn

I discovered shell script to setup openvpn and create client.

```
wget https://git.io/vpn -O openvpn-ubuntu-install.sh
```

while this shell script does create openvpn client ovpn file but the openvpn username is passwordless.
I want to know how I can create  a password for openvpn username ovpn cient file.
I am running openvpn on ubuntu 18.04 and on arm64 platform.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to password-protect that file? What sensitive information do you think is in there?

Comment: sorry I mean the openvpn username and password

Comment: So you want to password-protect the password? I don't follow.

Comment: The password you need to connect is given by your VPN provider.

Comment: I am the one who is running openvpn server, I created the openvpn profile, but that generates password less ovpn profile.